# Create Magento Coupon via API

Tags: magento

Is there a known way to create a new coupon code (Shopping Cart Price Rule) in Magento Community Edition through the API?

I would like to be able to auto-generate coupon codes using another webapp, and have them created in Magento simultaneously via some back-end communication. From what I can gather, there is no support in the default API for this.

Does anyone know of a way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my script that I use to create multiple discount codes.

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::app();

$code = $code = generateUniqueId(10); //coupon code
$amount = 10;   // discount amount

generateRule( $code, $amount, 'label', date('Y-m-d'));

function generateRule($code, $amount, $label, $from_date = '', $to_date = '', $name = ''){

    $name = (empty($name))? $label : $name;
    $labels[0] = $label;//default store label


    $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
    $coupon->setName($name)
    ->setDescription($name)
    ->setFromDate($from_date)
    ->setToDate($to_date)
    ->setCouponCode($code)
    ->setUsesPerCoupon(1)
    ->setUsesPerCustomer(1)
    ->setCustomerGroupIds(getAllCustomerGroups()) //an array of customer grou pids
    ->setIsActive(1)
    //serialized conditions.  the following examples are empty
    ->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}')
    ->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:"type";s:40:"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}')
    ->setStopRulesProcessing(0)
    ->setIsAdvanced(1)
    ->setProductIds('')
    ->setSortOrder(0)
    ->setSimpleAction('cart_fixed')
    ->setDiscountAmount($amount)
    ->setDiscountQty(null)
    ->setDiscountStep('0')
    ->setSimpleFreeShipping('0')
    ->setApplyToShipping('0')
    ->setIsRss(0)
    ->setWebsiteIds(getAllWbsites())
    ->setCouponType(2)
    ->setStoreLabels($labels)
    ;
    $coupon->save();
}


function getAllCustomerGroups(){
    //get all customer groups
    $customerGroupsCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
    $customerGroupsCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_code',array('nlike'=>'%auto%'));
//    $customerGroupsCollection->load();
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($customerGroupsCollection as $group){
    $groups[] = $group->getId();
    }
    return $groups;
}

function getAllWbsites(){
    //get all wabsites
    $websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection();
    $websiteIds = array();
    foreach ($websites as $website){
    $websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
    }
    return $websiteIds;
}

function generateUniqueId($length = null){
    $rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
    $rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId));
    $rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId);
    $rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
    if (!is_null($rndId)){
        return strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, $length));
    }
    return strtoupper($rndId);
}
```

The code is pretty much documented.

[Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html) does not support sales rules.

Comment: Thank you for the code! Is there any documentation on preparing the ConditionsSerialized and ActionsSerialized, or is that just a trial and check-the-results-in-the-database process?

Comment: Here is a link with more information on conditions and actions: http://mikebywaters.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/programmatically-create-shopping-cart-price-rules-with-conditions-and-actions/

Comment: Please approve this answer if is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 started supporting creating salesRules, in case anyone needs it.